# How to measure the PWM current with a DMM

Tags: pwm, current-measurement, multimeter

I have a Fluke 87V, which is a True-RMS DMM, and I would like to measure the current in my circuit. I have 2 motors being driven by a PWM so I wonder if the DC current or the AC current measurement of the DMM will be do the job for the PWM current. Is it there a recommended way to measure this kind of "mixed signal" using a regular DMM as a Fluke 87V?

Comment: You might want to consider a Hall effect sensor and an oscilloscope, which will show you both AC and DC current components up to reasonably high bandwidths. A good digital scope will compute RMS and average currents for complex periodic waveforms with ease.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I dont have a one at hand now...

Comment: Too bad you didn't buy the 89V, which has AC + DC TRMS measurement capability. A closed-loop Hall sensor as suggested by @Madmanguruman will only run you ~$25 and might be all you need.

Comment: 89V? I just know the 87V, and there isnt any 89V at Fluke's website either....

Answer (score 2):

> **Is it there a recommended way to measure this kind of "mixed signal"?**

Use a DMM with a AC+DC TRMS measurement capability?

Comment: I fogot a "using a regular DMM" :P

Answer (score 1):

What of sort frequencies, voltage levels?
(I'm not an AC power guy so if you blow something up...)
But I could imagine a shunt, and then a low pass and high pass filter.
Just RC's if you can throw power away.. and move heat away.
You'd have to work out the response functions.

Comment: Well I guess that's not a bad idea for low power applications, but I was hoping to measure some 10A at least, and filtering this can be tricky...

Comment: OK 10 A's, what's the PWM frequency?  With a 0.1 ohm resistor you'd have a volt of signal to play with.  Or 20 milli-ohm use the 200mV range on the DMM.

Comment: It's more like a generic question, not specific to one particular case, so many people can benefit from this, even if they projects are different. Mine had a 3KHz PWM.